# How to rename or give a specific location to save the coverage file on dotnet test

Tags: dot-net

I'm using `dotnet test` to get the code coverage of a given dotnet code project.
In this case final out put will be looks like below.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Backend Dev\test\Api.Test\TestResults\88de1678-d457-4e6c-a3fd-2d5786cddc13\ar0_2020-06-18.10_24_43.coverage
Total tests: 132. Passed: 66. Failed: 57. Skipped: 9.
Test Run Failed.
Test execution time: 44.3640 Seconds
```

As you can see the folder name is a unique ID and the report name also a unique ID.
So is there any way to get this result in to a my own folder and is there any way to rename the file name while it's generating to something readable.

Comment: Have you tried deleting all content of the TestResults folder before the execution and then fetching the only file in the folder after the execution?

Comment: Yeah I did, But still its creating a folder with an ID inside the test result folder.

Comment: Yes, then you can search for all files in the TestResults that end with .coverage. Since you delete all before, you will have only one afterward. find . -name "(pathToTestFolder)/*.jpg" does the job.

Comment: Thanks,At the moment I'm doing something like that, But I was looking for some better way :).